# Initialize a map of std::variant to represent a JSON file

Tags: c++, variant, c++17

As part of a school project, I have to read a JSON config file to fill a custom `Conf` object which is defined as follow:

```
struct ConfValue;
using ConfObject = std::map<std::string, ConfValue>;
using ConfArray = std::vector<ConfValue>;

/**
* Represents a configuration value.
*/
struct ConfValue {
    std::variant<std::monostate, ConfObject, ConfArray, std::string, long long, double, bool> v;
};

/**
* Configuration (format influenced by JSON).
*/
using Conf = ConfObject;
```

I would like to be able to construct a default object represented by this JSON file :

```
{
      "port": 4242,
      "module": "modheader",
      "modulePath": ["../modules/", "./modules"]
}
```

Which can provide me a map of what to search on the real config file, the type of each field as well as a default value for each of them.

I attempted to do that using braced initialization, but no matter what I try, this won't compile:

```
  Conf default_conf_{
    {"port", ConfValue{4242}},
    {"module", ConfValue{"modHeader"}},
    {"modulePath", ConfArray{"../modules/", "./modules"}}
  };
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible in c++ and if yes, how ? :)

Side question: Is it possible to get the type of a std::variant at run time ?

Comment: Side answer: You might get the [index](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/index) of the type.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks ! Any idea of how to link that back to a type except from maintaining an external enum ?

Comment: What do you want to do ? `variant<>::get_if` or `std::visit` might help.

Comment: @Jarod42 I use boost property tree json parser which store all data as string. So if I parse `"port"`from my json file, I get `"4343"` as a string. I want to be able to get the type of the variant contain in the field `"port"` of my `default_conf_` so that I can convert the `"4343"` I got from my json file to this type before putting it in the final conf object

Comment: You might want something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb620a48efb9a3c3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two independent issues here.

First, `4242` isn't going to work without more help. You can reduce that to:

```
std::variant<long long, bool> v = 4242; // error
```

The conversion is ambiguous. So you have to make no or the other a better match. Hence, `4242LL`.

Second, you just need more braces in the `modulePath` value - since we need to list-initialize all the `ConfValue`s, we can't just construct them:

```
Conf default_conf_{{
  {"port", {4242LL}},
  {"module", {"modHeader"}},
  {"modulePath", {ConfArray{{"../modules/"}, {"./modules"}}}}
}};
```

You need the `ConfArray` there basically to just identify what all these braces mean. If you added some constructors to `ConfValue`, you would be able to do away with that too.

Answer (score 2):

You might use:

```
Conf default_conf {
    {"port", ConfValue{4242LL}},
    {"module", ConfValue{"modHeader"}},
    {"modulePath", ConfValue{ConfArray{ConfValue{"../modules/"}, ConfValue{"./modules"}}}}
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/726235c95683decf)